# cannot access mysql from phpmyadmin

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I'm working on a dedicated OVH server, after installing everything needed (mysql, apache, php etc.) i've installed phpmyadmin (tried with adminer too) but it cannot access to the database.

Each time I try to login I get a #1045 error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The trouble is that, when running the installation, phpmyadmin asked me to define a password for a phpadmin user, and this user is now the only one allowed to connect, even root can't.

The phpmyadmin user created have no rights and therefore can't create database or such. I would like to allow any user defined to login into phpmyadmin.

The auth_type i'm using is 'cookie'.

PS: when I login on command line everything works great.

**EDIT:** Ok it seems that the password i used prevented me to login to phpmyadmin UI (unallowed character ?) I was using characters like **> < ° ( )** so I changed the password and everything works great.

Can someone confirm that some characters prevent phpmyadmin from logging in ?

Answer (score 0):

Check in phpMyAdmin's config file, see if the password in it is correct.

Alternatively, if your root doesn't have a password (assuming that this is a test DB), remove the password present in phpMyAdmin's config file.

Comment: the only password stored in phpmyadmin config is the one for the phpmyadmin user, created during installation, and this one works great but have no right. My root user have a password and can connect throught command line

Comment: Have you tried adding the root user to the config file? With a password you know is correct?